# Cost of minting 1 nft is not 0.00001

Tags: metaplex, nft

I used Metaplex to create an NFT. I thought it would cost to mint 0.00001 SOL, but it is costing a mint value of 0.0119812 SOL. I looked into transactions https://solscan.io/tx/wo5HUCh2xvzVtqFzu1nfBSd94K9Pj9cGNKWGQrpQpZgEnZCQz8jv53JXThCXbk1EMaZY7ZsDHRMRa4BaL7xjWTL and I couldn't figure out this cost. Well, I could see SOL debt from my account, but as I said before, I thought it would cost only 0.00001. Am I doing something wrong? I need to create 20.000 unique NFTs.

Here is my code to mint/create NFT

```
const txMasterMint = await Metaplex.actions.mintNFT({
    connection: connection,
    wallet: masterWallet,
    uri: metadataURI,
    maxSupply: 0 });
```

Comment: what made you think it would only cost 0.00001 SOL?  that sounds like it's accurate for the transaction fee, but neglects storage rent costs

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are doing everything correctly. The costs are that "high".

What you are paying is the fee that is required to pay for the rent of the on chain accounts.

Minting will become cheaper with the new token metadata standard which is currently in a RFC status.

Comment: It comes from the fact that each NFT, being a non-native token (!=SOL) need a dedicated token account, hence the rent-exemption surcharge.